# animated width resizing 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have this animated width changer, it seems to auto resize to 100% when i click expand on this script then click my header logo. any ideas why?

```
$(".fluid").hide();
$(".fixed").click(function() {
  $("#mainwidth").animate({width: "1024px"}, 800);
    $(this).hide();
    $(".fluid").show();
    $.cookie("width","fixed", {expires: 365});
  return false;
});
$(".fluid").click(function() {
    $("#mainwidth").animate({width: "95%"}, 800);
    $(this).hide();
    $(".fixed").show();
    $.cookie("width","fluid", {expires: 365});
    return false;
});
if($.cookie("width") == "fixed") {
    $(".fixed").hide();
    $(".fluid").show();
    $("#mainwidth").css("width","1024px");
};

text-align: left;
line-height: 1.4;
margin: auto auto;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: without your html and css, its impossible to say or reproduce your problem. keep in mind that by default, border grows outside so if your border width is more than 2.5%, it will add up to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs in the following block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".fluid").hide();
    $(".fixed").click(function() {
      $("#mainwidth").animate({width: "1024px"}, 800);
        $(this).hide();
        $(".fluid").show();
        $.cookie("width","fixed", {expires: 365});
      return false;
    });
    $(".fluid").click(function() {
        $("#mainwidth").animate({width: "95%"}, 800);
        $(this).hide();
        $(".fixed").show();
        $.cookie("width","fluid", {expires: 365});
        return false;
    });
    if($.cookie("width") == "fixed") {
        $(".fixed").hide();
        $(".fluid").show();
        $("#mainwidth").css("width","1024px");
    };
});
</script>
```

lets have a look at the last statement:

```
if($.cookie("width") == "fixed") {
   $(".fixed").hide();
    $(".fluid").show();
    $("#mainwidth").css("width","1024px");
};
```

it instructs the browser to change the width when page loads. if the `width` cookie value is **"fixed"**, then set width to `1024px`. however, what happens if the page reloads while the cookie value is **"fluid"** ?

 when you click the logo, it reloads the page. hence, if the cookie value is fluid, the width will not be set to the relevant value. just add another block of code to handle the situation where the cookie value is **"fluid"** and it will work fine.

```
if($.cookie("width") == "fixed") {
   $(".fixed").hide();
    $(".fluid").show();
    $("#mainwidth").css("width","1024px");
}
else if($.cookie("width") == "fluid") {
    $(".fluid").hide();
    $(".fixed").show();
    $("#mainwidth").css("width","95%");
};
```

Comment: Ok i have it fixed now.  much appreciated for your time and help.

Comment: its not about jQuery, its just plain logic :) you handle one case, but not the other. if you notice, the website goes 100% only when you click logo while the width is 95%, if you click logo when width is 1024px it stays the same way. this is because you only handled 1 out of 2 scenarios. just add the `else if` block to your code, the way i wrote it, and it should work. please dont forget to accept my answer if it helped :) (green V on the left)